# Path.Combine concatenates only last two string

Tags: c#

Hi I have an issue with Path.Combine that it does not return the corect result. Here is what I mean.I ave to combine 4 strings into a bath:

```
string basePath = "D:\\Programare\\Visual Studio\\TFS Workspace\\CodeArt\\Development\\CodeArt\\Backend\\WebApi\\CodeArt.WebApi\\bin\\..\\Content\\"
string userId = "4d52ec77-966a-480a-a4c3-c1ff67438fe9";
string filePath = "\\Avatar";
string storageFileName = "ffdc24a9-f553-41ce-aa33-042b07fcfdab.png";

var result  = Path.Combine(basePath , userId , filePath , storageFileName);
```

Now for some reason my this code returns only "\Avatar\ffdc24a9-f553-41ce-aa33-042b07fcfdab.png".

Am I doing something wrong why am aint Path.Combine concatantes all the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From MSDN: [`Path.Combine(String, String, String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782933%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> path1 should be an absolute path (for example, "d:\archives" or
>   "\archives\public").If one of the subsequent paths is also an
>   absolute path, the **combine operation discards all previously combined
>   paths and resets to that absolute path**.

Asper the MSDN documentation Path1 should be an **`Absolute Path`** and you should not have **`Absolute Path`** in any subsequent paths

Replace This:

```
string filePath = "\\Avatar";
```

With This:

```
string filePath = "Avatar";
```